# How to make a preloader background to fit the entire page with current gif?

Tags: jquery, html, css, preloader, codepen

I am trying to help my brother to create a preloader that he makes the custom GIF for, but we are running into issues that the gif needs to be a certain size as well as have the preloader mask everything prior to everything being fully loaded. I have been trying to adapt some code I got on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/CrazyWulf/pen/zVMWqq), this is what I have so far. This is an example of what we want it to do, that GIF, but don't want to see any of the other content behind the preloader.

```js
var preloader;

function preload(opacity) {
    if(opacity <= 0) {
        showContent();
    }
    else {
        preloader.style.opacity = opacity;
        window.setTimeout(function() { preload(opacity - 0.05) }, 100);
    }
}

function showContent() {
    preloader.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    preloader = document.getElementById('preloader');
    preload(1);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url('https://www.studio-aegis.com/uploads/1/0/3/8/10380626/background-images/245373741.png') no-repeat center center;
  color: white;
}
#preloader {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: visible;
    background: url('https://www.studio-aegis.com/uploads/1/0/3/8/10380626/custom_themes/921719032455054188/files/Orphan---Run.gif') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
 }

#content {
    display: none;
 }
```

```html
 <body>
    <div id="preloader"></div>
    <div id="content">Page content!</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/CrazyWulf/pen/zVMWqq  
Sorry, I can't figure out how to put the inset of the codepen in here.

Comment: try background-size:cover

Comment: @FaizalHussain I tried that before, but that makes the entire GIF huge, which isn't needed, basically that level of coverage, but using the smaller GIF size and total coverage with a black screen

Comment: It's not letting you put the CodePen here because you're supposed to be putting code here. We want questions that will be helpful for a lot of people for a long time, and when that pen gets deleted, this question will no longer be helpful. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to add a runnable example here on Stack Overflow. See [ask] also.

Comment: @HereticMonkeyThanks, i guess I kept trying to add the line of code instead of opening the stack snippet. but I see how to do it now. And thank you to those that edited this to be in compliance! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set background-color to #000 and change the background to background-image like

```
background-image: url(https://www.studio-aegis.com/uploads/1/0/3/8/10380626/custom_themes/921719032455054188/files/Orphan---Run.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
background-color: #000;
```

Comment: This might do the trick! Now to try and emplement it w/o breaking his site, haha. Many thanks for the prompt responses.